# Parse query returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am doing a query and I am checking to see if the value in the column "Parent", which is a pointer, is equal to a string, newLogObjectId.  I obviously cannot do this since a pointer and a string are a different value type, (returns nil).  When I look at the data in Parse, I notice that in the Parent column, the objectId is listed, but within a button, which when clicked, load the NewLog class.

How do I change "Parent" be the objectId in the Pointer in the code "query1.whereKey("Parent", equalTo:newLogObjectId)"? Something like "Parent.objectId"

```
    //ObjectId of row of Marker Selected, a string, for example, "MCeKMyxRIt"
    let newLogObjectId = objectIdArray[markerIndex]

    //Query ComparablePhotos class
    let query1 = PFQuery(className: "ComparablePhotos")

    //Grab all rows of Parent, equal to newLogObjectId ex: "MCeKMyxRIt"
    //Issue: "Parent" is a pointer, not a String.  Parent has an objectId
    query1.whereKey("Parent", equalTo:newLogObjectId)

    //Get result as an object
    viewRecordObject = query1.findObjects() as! [PFObject]
```

[image]

Comment: is query1.whereKey("Parent", equalTo:newLog.ObjectId) not working? typically you access username,objectId or whatever column your object is in by .objectId, .username Etc.... Or... query1.Parent.query.findobjectsInBackgroundwithBlock {

Comment: I would query the NewLog class `whereKey("objectId", containedIn:objectIdArray)` to get all PFObjects with the associated object IDs. Have this query fetch the Parent field, then iterate through your objects to get each Parent.

Comment: No steve, it is not working.  I believe if it was Android it would work that way.

Comment: And Connor, how do I have the query fetch the Parent field?  is there a fetch method

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when it comes to images pictures or big data it is better to use the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method

```
   var query = PFQuery(className:"")
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in {
     if error == nil{
      // do whatever you want 
       if let data = objects as![PFObject]{
       // now you could just append your array with data
       // something like self.arrayofObjects.append(data)
        }
       }
  }
```

method because it let you check error and also make easier to add those objects to your array.

Comment: How would I grab the row that the pointer pointer references?

Comment: see update code now you could just append any array with data objects in the code

Answer (score 0):

If you only have an objectId, create a new ParseObject, set its objectId to newLogObjectId, and then use that newly created object (which is a pointer), in your query.

```
var myNewLog = PFObject(className: "NewLog")
myPointer.objectId = newLogObjectId
query1.whereKey("Parent", myNewLog)
```